# Possible configurations on the subset problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, additive-combinatorics

Let $A=\left\{ a_{i}\right\} $ be a sequence of $n$ positive numbers
such that $\sum a_{i}=1$. We define $C\left(A\right)=\left\{ \left\{ b_{i}\right\} \subset\left\{ 1,2..,n\right\} :\sum a_{b_{i}}=\frac{1}{2}\right\} $
. We say that a set $B\subset2^{\left\{ 1,2,..,n\right\} }$ is feasible,
if and only if there is some $A$, such that $B=C\left(A\right)$.

Which are sufficient and necessary conditions for characterizing
feasible sets?

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that a nice characterization is unlikely to exist, since the decision version of this problem, i.e., the problem of deciding whether a feasible set exists seems to be equivalent to the [partition problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem).

Comment: Yes, It is a possibility. But if such nice characterization exists, there is also the possibility of being useless for solving the NP complete problem. Actually, I thinked in such problem because it is difficult for me to see the opposite. Thanks, for pointing that more accurate related problem.